# Php mail not Send sometimes

Tags: php, email

here is my php code to send email.

```
  <?php

       class mailer {
       public function send_request_mail($to, $msg) {
       $from="abcd@xyz.com";
       $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n".'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n".'From: ' . $from . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $from . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion ();
       $message = "ip 192.168.0.9:9035";
       $subject = "subject";
       mail ( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

             }
       }

$mail=new mailer();

$mail->send_request_mail("abcd@xyz.com", "msg");
?>
```

sometimes its works(for some messages).when i try to send an ip address like above,it fails.help me

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are doing Well.

PHP must be configured correctly in the php.ini file with the details of how your system sends email. Open php.ini file available in /etc/ directory and find the section headed [mail function].

Windows users should ensure that two directives are supplied. The first is called SMTP that defines your email server address. The second is called sendmail_from which defines your own email address.

The configuration for Windows should look something like this:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = smtp.secureserver.net

; For win32 only
sendmail_from = webmaster@tutorialspoint.com
```

Linux users simply need to let PHP know the location of their sendmail application. The path and any desired switches should be specified to the sendmail_path directive.

The configuration for Linux should look something like this:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = 

; For win32 only
sendmail_from = 

; For Unix only
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

PHP makes use of mail() function to send an email. This function requires three mandatory arguments that specify the recipient's email address, the subject of the the message and the actual message additionally there are other two optional parameters.

```
mail( to, subject, message, headers, parameters );
```

Example:

Following example will send an HTML email message to xyz@somedomain.com copying it to afgh@somedomain.com. You can code this program in such a way that it should recieve all content from the user and then it should send an email.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sending HTML email using PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
   $to = "xyz@somedomain.com";
   $subject = "This is subject";
   $message = "<b>This is HTML message.</b>";
   $message .= "<h1>This is headline.</h1>";
   $header = "From:abc@somedomain.com \r\n";
   $header = "Cc:afgh@somedomain.com \r\n";
   $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
   $header .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
   $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
   if( $retval == true )
   {
      echo "Message sent successfully...";
   }
   else
   {
      echo "Message could not be sent...";
   }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this will be usefull to you !!! Cheers !!

Waiting for your positive comments !!!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) because there is a good chance your email will end up in spam or junk box when you use `mail()` function.

Here is a sample code using PHPMailer,

```
    <?php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->From = 'abcd@xyz.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'ip 192.168.0.9:9035';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```